# Combining two columns conditionally in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column based on the values of two other columns. The values in the initial columns are 1 and 2. For the new column, I want the value to be 1 if the value in either of the first two columns is 1 and to be 0 otherwise. (If the person is either `Vegetarian` or `Vegan`, the `VegYesNo` column should be 1. Otherwise, it should be 0).

```
Vegetarian Vegan VegYesNo
1          2     1
2          2     0
2          1     1
```

I've searched the other questions on here and didn't find one that gave me an answer, but please let me know if you know of a question that has a solution that would work.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the base R function `ifelse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a `data.frame`

```
data = data.frame(vegetarian = c(1,2,2),Vegan = c(2,2,1))
data$VegYesNo = as.numeric(data$vegetarian==1 | data$Vegan==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with:

```
mydata$VegYesNo <- as.integer(rowSums(mydata == 1) > 0)
```

Or with:

```
mydata$VegYesNo <- 1 * (rowSums(mydata == 1) > 0)
```

The result:

```
> mydata
  Vegetarian Vegan VegYesNo
1          1     2        1
2          2     2        0
3          2     1        1
```

---

Data:

```
mydata <- read.table(text="Vegetarian Vegan VegYesNo
1          2     1
2          2     0
2          1     1", header=TRUE)[,-3]
```

Comment: If the Vegetarian and Vegan columns are just two columns within a much larger data frame, how do I ensure this function is only drawing from those two columns?

Comment: @melbez you can then use the column indexes as in `rowSums(mydata[,1:2] == 1)` for example

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` package:

```
mydf <- text <- "Vegetarian Vegan
1          2
2          2
2          1"
mydf <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
    mutate(VegYesNo=case_when(
        Vegetarian==1 | Vegan==1 ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0
    ))
```

The result is:

```
  Vegetarian Vegan VegYesNo
1          1     2        1
2          2     2        0
3          2     1        1
```